# Importing several csv files and concatenating in Python using pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, concatenation

I have several csv files that I am trying to load an concatenate using pandas. There have been similar questions asked but the answers do not appear to be working for me. Basically, the code is loading the csv files and concatenating but the structure of the DF is strange (the number of columns grows unexpectedly). Bit of background: I am a new convert from Matlab and I actually have this code working in Matlab and I just want to get it running in Python. Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

filelist = glob.glob('/.../*.csv')
DF = pd.DataFrame()
list_ = []
    for i in filelist:
        tmp = pd.read_csv(i, header=1, skiprows=0, index_col=None)
        list_.append(tmp)
        DF = pd.concat(list_)
DF.to_csv('/.../All.csv')
```

The csv files are structured like this:

```
TestDate,City,State,ZipCode,County,Num,A,B,C
9/1/16,X,AL,X,X,29,negative,positive,positive
9/1/16,X,AL,X,X,1,negative,negative,negative
9/1/16,X,AL,X,X,10,negative,negative,negative
```

The output looks like this:

```
,11/14/16,11/7/16,17,29,32,X,71901,9/1/16,99771,AK,AL,AR,X,X,X,X,Nome Census Area,X,negative,negative.1,negative.2,positive,positive.1
0,,,,1.0,,X,,9/1/16,,,AL,,X,X,,,,,negative,,,negative,negative
1,,,,10.0,,X,,9/1/16,,,AL,,X,X,,,,,negative,,,negative,negative
2,,,,11.0,,X,,9/1/16,,,AL,,X,X,,,,,negative,,,negative,negative
```

Comment: Can you fix your indentation? As is this should raise a syntax issue due to `for` line's *unexpected indent*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is `header=1` which tells pandas that the second row should be treated as header rather than the first.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
data="""TestDate,City,State,ZipCode,County,Num,A,B,C
9/1/16,X,AL,X,X,29,negative,positive,positive
9/1/16,X,AL,X,X,1,negative,negative,negative
9/1/16,X,AL,X,X,10,negative,negative,negative"""
df=pd.read_csv(StringIO(data))
print(df)
```

```
  TestDate City State ZipCode County  Num         A         B         C
0   9/1/16    X    AL       X      X   29  negative  positive  positive
1   9/1/16    X    AL       X      X    1  negative  negative  negative
2   9/1/16    X    AL       X      X   10  negative  negative  negative
```

```
df=pd.read_csv(StringIO(data),header=1,skiprows=0)
print(df)
```

```
9/1/16  X  AL X.1 X.2  29  negative  positive positive.1
0  9/1/16  X  AL   X   X   1  negative  negative   negative
1  9/1/16  X  AL   X   X  10  negative  negative   negative
```

The problem is that you have many different cities in the first row in the respective dataframes, so more and more columns are inserted into the DataFrame, which means you have too little columns in the data for each respective file and everything gets super messy.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian! That fixed it. I spent hours on this -- so embarrassed.